# Como puedo hacer para coger una variable de usuario de otra pagina php sin $_SESSION

Tags: php, html5

tengo dos paginas php en una tengo un formulario y quiero coger la variable del email desde la otra pagina. Como lo hago sin utilizar $_SESSION. Quiero hacer esto por que desde el servidor no me funciona utilizar $_SESSION ni start_session()

```
<header class='main' id='h1'>
  <span class="right"><a href='../HTML5/layout.html'>LogOut</a> </span>
  <span> Usuario: <?php echo "$_GET[email]"; ?> </span>
  <h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
</header>
```

Esto no me funciona

Comment: puedes utillizar GET y mandas la variable en la url o POST y lo que quieres enviar lo colocas en un input hidden

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo en esto y no se como dices. Podrias ponerme un ejemplo? @Oscar Diaz

Comment: escribe el codigo completo que tienes  de las 2 paginas que dices para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si no entendi mal lo que queres hacer, si ya tenes la variable en otra pagina .php podrias que pasarte la variable tramite un form con metodo POST :

```
<form class="" action="(url pagina de destino de los datos)" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="e-mail" value="ejemplo@ejemplo.com">
   <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

en vez si la tiene que inserir el usuario seria :

```
<form class="" action="(url pagina de destino de los datos)" method="POST">
   <input type="email" name="e-mail">
   <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

y en la pagina que lo recibis (la que pusiste en el action) :

```
<?php 
   $mail = $_POST['e-mail'];
?>
```

espero que te pueda ayudar en algo

Answer (score 0):

En la parte superior de tu código debieras agregar con un `include` de esta manera para hacer el llamado de otro archivo `PHP` que contenga lo que es la conexión o el llamado a las variables y de esta manera podras utilizar el `$GET_[email]` sin problemas, a continuación dejo el como debes incluir el archivo que contiene la conexión o la interacción con la base de datos:

```
<?php
include('conectar.php');    
$linkt=conectar();
extract($_GET);
?>
   <header class='main' id='h1'>
     <span class="right"><a href='../HTML5/layout.html'>LogOut</a> </span>
     <span> Usuario: <?php echo "$_GET[email]"; ?> </span>
       <h2>Quiz: crazy questions
       </h2>
   </header>  
<?php
mysqli_close($linkt);
?>
<br />
```

donde `$linkt` es la conexión con tu base de datos y `extract($GET);` para sacar las variables que provienen desde el otro archivo.